# Bulk downsampling list of wave objects using seewave::resamp

Tags: r, lapply, wav, downsampling

I am trying to downsample a list of `wave` objects using `seewave::resamp`.

To get my list I have imported a .wav file and split it into 10 second clips following @Jota 's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20713513/efficiently-split-a-large-audio-file-in-r)

So to get my list of `wave` object I have done the following (this is using the example from the above answer):

```
library(seewave)

# your audio file (using example file from seewave package)
data(tico)
audio <- tico # this is an S4 class object

# the frequency of your audio file
freq <- 22050

# the length and duration of your audio file
totlen <- length(audio)
totsec <- totlen/freq

# the duration that you want to chop the file into
seglen <- 0.5

# defining the break points
breaks <- unique(c(seq(0, totsec, seglen), totsec))
index <- 1:(length(breaks)-1)

# a list of all the segments
subsamps <- lapply(index, function(i) audio[(breaks[i]*freq):(breaks[i+1]*freq)])
```

I now have my list of `wave` objects. If do the following for individual objects it works:

```
resamp(subsamps[[1]], f = 48000, g = 22050, output = "Wave")
```

But when I try and do it to the list of objects it comes up with an error:

```
test_wave_downsample <- lapply(subsamps, function(i) resamp(subsamps[[i]], f = 22050, g = 8000, output = "Wave"))
 
Error in subsamps[[i]] : invalid subscript type 'S4'
```

I am pretty sure this is something to do with the way I using `lapply` as the S4 object is not an issue when done individually, but as someone who is new to using the `apply` family I am not sure what.

I have had a look around an can't find much on using existing functions within `lapply` or if that can be an issue.

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: Aren't you feeding the **contents** of  `subsamps` as the values of your index `i` here?  Maybe try  `lapply(1:length(subsamps), function(i)....`

Comment: Yes. I have been told this since posting the questions this morning. I have edited my question with the solution that worked for me.

Comment: @TomCLewis could you post your "edit" answer as an answer, and accept it, rather than having it embedded in the question? That way if anyone else has a similar question they can scroll right down to the accepted answer.

Comment: @selene sure thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asking around I have been given the a solution that works:

```
f <- function(x) {
  resamp(x, f = 22050, g = 8000, output = "Wave")
}
​
test_wave_downsample <- lapply(subsamps, f)
```